# Open infowindow on marker click with ng-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

**1** - How to open `infowindow` on `marker` click with [ng-maps](http://willleahy.info/ng-maps/)?

**2** - Can the `infowindow`be just on top of `marker`, like the second map?

HTML file with two maps (one loaded with ng-maps, *not working as I want* and other with pure Google Maps API, *working as I want*): [github gist](https://gist.github.com/hmaesta/d1ffa25f4ac7a87f7ab0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** According to [source code](https://github.com/procterw/ng-maps/blob/master/src/directives/infowindow.js) of `infowindow` directive, info window gets opened once it is rendered and there is no option to make it hidden by default. In order to prevent such behavior you could utilize [`ng-if` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<infowindow ng-if="infowindow.open" options="infoWindowOptions" position="map.center">
      <h4>Line One</h4> <br/> Line two <br /> Line three
</infowindow>


$scope.marker = {
        events: {
            click: function() {
                $scope.infowindow.open = true;
                $scope.$apply()
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.infowindow = {
        open: false
    }
```

**2** InfoWindow position could be adjusted using [`pixelOffset` property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions):

```
$scope.infoWindowOptions = function(){
        return { 
            pixelOffset: {height: -32, width:0 }
        };    
}


<infowindow ng-if="infowindow.open" options="infoWindowOptions" position="map.center">
      <h4>Line One</h4> <br/> Line two <br /> Line three
</infowindow>
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngMaps'])
    .controller('Main', function($scope) {
   

        $scope.map = {
            center: [14.9035822, -24.3588356],
            options: function() {
                return {
                    zoom: 10
                }
            },
        }
        $scope.marker = {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    $scope.infowindow.open = true;
                    $scope.$apply()
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.infowindow = {
            open: false
        }

        $scope.infoWindowOptions = function(){
            return { 
                pixelOffset: {height: -32, width:0 }
            };    
        }
    });
```

```css
body,
html {
     margin: 0;
}
        
.google-map
{
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     margin: 3em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://willleahy.info/ng-maps/bower_components/ng-maps/dist/ng-maps.js'></script>

<div ng-app='App' ng-controller="Main">
    <map ng-transclude class='google-map' center="map.center" options="map.options">
        <marker position="map.center" events="marker.events"></marker>
        <infowindow ng-if="infowindow.open" options="infoWindowOptions" position="map.center">
          <h4>Line One</h4> <br/> Line two <br /> Line three
         </infowindow>
    </map>
</div>
```

As a side note I would like to mention that there are more feature complete implementations available at the moment for Google Maps such as [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) or [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you pointed out, the are better options right now – like ng-map, what I ended up using. Thank you!